# WiFi randomly disconnects and sometimes fails to authenticate again

Tags: 16.04, networking, authentication

I am using Xenial - Ubuntu.

This is the outcome of `dmesg`:

```
[ 2195.776888] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 94:0c:6d:b7:b2:de by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2218.981806] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 2219.032521] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 2225.238469] wlp2s0: authenticate with 94:0c:6d:b7:b2:de
[ 2225.246594] wlp2s0: send auth to 94:0c:6d:b7:b2:de (try 1/3)
```

It deauthenticates randomly for no apparent reason and I have to turn networking off and on again to fix it. This works a few times, but eventually I will lose the connection completely (it will always get to try 3/3 and fail it). The only thing of help I've found is rebooting.

[Here I've run the script AskUbuntu suggests to diagnose the networking.](https://pastebin.com/raw/F9RzLWvc)

The script is not from the exact moment of the complete failure. Other devices work flawlessly in the same network.

Answer (score 2):

We notice this in your wireless info:

```
Pokojicek  <MAC 'Pokojicek' [AN5]>  Infra  6 2437 MHz 54 Mbit/s 78 ▂▄▆_ WEP yes *
```

Many Linux drivers do not work well with WEP. As well, it is quite insecure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy

> In 2005, a group from the U.S. Federal Bureau of Investigation gave a
>   demonstration where they cracked a WEP-protected network in 3 minutes
>   using publicly available tools.

Almost every device manufactured in the last ten years or so supports the more secure WPA2-AES.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: Thank you for the info on security, unfortunately the router isn't mine but I will take a look into it soon. Setting the region didn't help. I also disabled IPv6 but the problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

Could try this soon after reboot:

```
sudo iwconfig
```

See if your wireless card is listed as `power management on`, then run the command below (replacing `CARDNAME` with the real name of your device, e.g. `wlp3s0`):

```
sudo iwconfig CARDNAME power off
```

If this corrects your issue, you can edit the following file to make it permanent:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Change the `wifi.powersave` setting from `3` to `2`

Comment: It says `Power Management:off` actually.

Comment: You should probably recheck the config file path you suggested. I doubt it contains any spaces.